# What does $$@ and the pipe symbol in Makefile stand for?

Tags: makefile

In the following Makefile definition:

1. What does the `$$@` in the second last line stand for?
2. What about the `|` symbol in the middle line?

```
define KERNEL_RULE
$(DESTDIR)/$(1) : kernel_modules
$(DEST_DIR)/$(1) : $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) | $(DEST_DIR)
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) $$@
endef
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Suppose you were writing an ordinary rule:

```
$(DEST_DIR)/foo : $(SOURCE_DIR)/foo
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/foo $(DEST_DIR)/foo
```

That works, but the redundancy is troublesome. Sooner or later you'll change `$(DEST_DIR)/foo` in the preq but forget to change it in the rule. And the rule is hard to read. So we put in an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
$(DEST_DIR)/foo : $(SOURCE_DIR)/foo
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/foo $@
```

When this rule runs, `$@` will be expanded to the name of the target, `$(DEST_DIR)/foo`. (We can do even better than that, but let's stop there.)

Now we want to make sure that `$(DEST_DIR)` exists before this rule runs, but we don't *want* it to be a prerequisite exactly, because the absence of that directory shouldn't be enough to cause this rule to run. So we make it an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```
$(DEST_DIR)/foo : $(SOURCE_DIR)/foo | $(DEST_DIR)
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/foo $@
```

Now we want many rules like this, for different targets, and instead of doing it [the smart way](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), we'll use a ["canned recipe"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes), sort of a template for creating rules on the fly.

```
# This won't work
define KERNEL_RULE
$(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) : kernel_modules
$(DEST_DIR)/$(1) : $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) | $(DEST_DIR)
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) $@
endef
```

The problem is that when we evaluate this definition, `$@` will be expanded, and since it isn't a rule yet, it will expand to nothing. So we change it to `$$@`:

```
# This will work
define KERNEL_RULE
$(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) : kernel_modules
$(DEST_DIR)/$(1) : $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) | $(DEST_DIR)
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(1) $$@
endef
```

When Make calls this definition, `$$@` expands to `$@`, then if/when it runs the rule, `$@` will expand to the name of the target.

Comment: "the absence of that directory shouldn't be enough to cause this rule to run" I don't understand that. That rule is triggered by some other rule trying to make `destdir/foo`. The directory is a prereq, so it doesn't cause that rule to run no matter what.